# Game walls not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been working on a game on Unity, and since I'm new, I have to search up how to do things. To make sure my player doesn't fly off the platform, and so the video told to make walls, and then just place them on the side. But, when I tried to see what would happen if I run into them, if I just barely press the button to push against it, I'm fine, but when  I continuously hold down the arrow key, I just go right through it. I even thickened the walls to help prevent it, but it didn't work. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Did you add the proper collider to your wall?

Answer (score 3):

This could be happening for a number of reasons.

1. Your object is moving too fast.
2. One of your objects, either your player or your walls' collider is not set properly.
3. Your RigidBody is not set properly.

You already tried to thicken the walls. Have you checked if that also thicken the collider? (I suppose you are using a box collider).

If that doesn't work try playing with your RigidBody configurations. Go into the RigidBody settings of the player AND the walls and set collision detection from discrete to continuous dynamic for both.

Another thing that might be happening is that your player is pushing your walls. You can prevent that from happening by adding mass to your walls or simply adding constraints.

I'm not completely sure but I think physics and collisions are detected every fixed update... if your player is the length of a collider in less than 0.02, you'll simply teleport or get stuck.

The easiest solution is increasing your box collider. Playing with RigiBody might solve and if none of that work, you can try `Mathf.Clamp` which is also a great solution. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html

[Edit] As suggested by Andrea ジーティーオー you can also set "is kinematic" on your RigidBody, this is actually the right way to do it. You 'll only be able to move using a script!

Comment: Great answer. Regarding point 3, I would specify the control about the "is kinematic" property of the rigidbody itself, it is usually the problem.

Comment: You are right. I totally forgot about this setting. Already edited my answer, thank you.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, for a bit, but then, after I did some testing and added colors for the walls, added enemies and empty game objects(for the positions they go to),and then the walls didn't work again. I used the "is kinematic", can you please help me again? I also tried to use continuous, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Adding colors, enemies and empty objects should not interfere with the Collision and RigidBody. How fast is your player?

Comment: 7.5f what? You need to tell me the exact function you are using to move your player, than maybe I can help you.